# Deleting an XML tag using C#

Tags: c#, xml

**FIRST EDIT**
I'm fetching the **Child 1** tag into a DropDownList in my C# form, Plz suggest the best practise code (C#) for deleting a Particular Parent tag & all it's child tags in an XML file.
Example of my xml file:

```
    <Parents>
      <Parent>
        <Child 1>Something</Child 1>
        <Child 2>Something</Child 2>
        <Child 3>Something</Child 3>
        <Child 4>Something</Child 4>
      </Parent>
      <Parent>
        <Child 1>Something 1</Child 1>
        <Child 2>Something 1</Child 2>
        <Child 3>Something 1</Child 3>
        <Child 4>Something 1</Child 4>
      </Parent>
    </Parents>
```

I mean something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<[Length of xml doc]; i++)
{
  if (Child 1 == ComboBox1.Text && Child 2 == richTextBox1.Text)
    // Delete <Parent> tag of that Child 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into XmlDocument and XmlNode and see what you can do with them. [See here](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=312) and there are also some good examples from [msdn here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302158.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small example. Hope this helps!.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.Load("myXmlFile.xml");

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.ChildNodes)
{
    if (<node.value matches your criteria>)
    {
        doc.RemoveChild(node);
    }

}
```